# Define custom homepage

Tags: controllers, home, routing

We have a Dashboard package which can be accessed as follows: www.shop.be/dashboard. How can we make sure that this always is the homepage? So, www.shop.be will always show the dashboard instead of its default homepage?

Answer (score 1):

Go to system config->general, make homepage to this cms page